# Debugging JavaScript (FBJS) in Facebook

Tags: javascript, debugging, facebook

I am developing an application on Facebook. I am running into some vague situation that I want to debug. The problem is that Facebook adds MUCH wrapping code and changes the name, not to mention that it already uses a modified version of JavaScript called FBJS. These things make it almost impossible to use tools like FireBug to debug the code. Does anybody have a suggestion for such cases? I am thinking of some debugging library that traces the code, variables, etc., and show me some results in some other window, or something like that.

Comment: Are you using namespacing with your JavaScript? Otherwise you're likely to encounter conflicting global variables..

Comment: I am not sure if this is the case for you but you can find the iframe source and load it in a new page. That's what I do for debugging my facebook app.

Comment: @graham, there is no problem with global variables, Facebook already append the application ID to all variables to avoid conflicts. The problem is how to debug the code.

Comment: @Nylon, unfortunately, I am developing my application using FBML not iFrame, so I am using FBJS actually rather than JavaScript. Actually, let me update the subject of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the line `debugger` to your javascript where you want to break. Firebug should break point on that line.

Comment: You mean add this line anywhere on the code on its own?!! Won't this be considered a syntax error by all browsers' JavaScript interpreters?

Comment: yes, but if you have firebug installed in your firefox browser, then it breaks on that line. Obviously, take it out before you deploy to production.